# Flutter Text overflow doesn't work for the second row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a column with text. I don't know the exact size of the incoming string, so I want some of my texts to end with an ellipsis.

```
  Flexible(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 16),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(_model._schoolName,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,  //this one works
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontSize: 18)),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 12),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.grey[700]),
                  Container(width: 8),
                  Text(_model._guides,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,  //this one doesn't work
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 12),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.attach_money, color: Colors.grey[700]),
                  Container(width: 8),
                  Text(_model._priceFrom,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400))
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
```

First time I use `TextOverflow.ellipsis` works and the second doesn't. Can anybody explain why? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just wrap your `Text` in another `Flexible`, like so:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.grey[700]),
    Container(width: 8),
    Flexible(
      child: Text(_model._guides,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, //this one now works :)
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
    ),
  ],
),
```

The first `Flexible` wrapping your main `Column` sets the layout for its direct children, that's why the first `Text` works, because it's a direct child (layout wise) of the `Column`. But then you add a `Row` which sets its own children's layout, and the overflow won't work because it doesn't has any width constraint, by wrapping that `Text` in a `Flexible` you tell it to grab all the space it can up to its parent width, and apply whatever `TextOverflow` you need, `ellipsis` in this case.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you need to tell the `Text` widget the max width for it to wrap. In a `Row` you can set it's `mainAxisSize` to `MainAsixSize.max` and wrap the `Text` widget on a `Flexible` to take the remaining space.

```
Row(
  mainAxisSize: mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: <Widget>[
    Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.grey[700]),
    Container(width: 8),
    Flexible(
      child: Text(_model._guides,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,  //this one doesn't work
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14,
          color: Colors.black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

This will set the text to a single line text and append it with an ellipsis. Note that it will only start appending once the width exceeds that of the parent widget.

```
Text(
  "Really long text here!",
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  maxLines: 1,
)
```